# Average value of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

> I need to calculate the average value of my datas, my datas are in an
>   array the problem is when i parseInt them into an integer i only get
>   one value back and when try as an example following thing:

```
console.log(array[0]/24)
```

> i dont get nothing
>
> this is my array:
>   info my array is coming from php to js (php connected to api)

```
var signal_GW1 = dataFromAjax.data.data1.map(function(innerData){
   return innerData.map(function(row){
       return row[1];
   });
});

console.log(signal_GW1);
```

> //OUTPUT on BROWSER CONSOLE

```
[Array(136)]
0: Array(136)
[0 … 99]
0: "-59"
1: "-59"
2: "-59"
3: "-59"
4: "-53"
5: "-63"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the average of your array you could do the following.

As the response from the server is returning strings you need to use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert to a number.

```js
const array = ['-59', '-57', '-59', '-57'];
const average = array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => parseInt(accumulator) + parseInt(currentValue)) / array.length;
console.log(average);
```

Comment: i get NaN typeof  = object

Comment: @noSkill06s  Run the snippet, you will get 3.

Comment: @noSkill06s Try it again with the updated answer, your array contains strings which I hadn't taken into account

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

let sum = 0

for (const value of myArray) { sum += value; }

const average = sum / myArray.length

console.log(`Average: ${average}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically: calculate the sum using `Array.prototype.reduce`, and divide the sum by the number of `Array` values (i.e. its `length`). [About Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const x = Array.apply(null, new Array(5))
 .map(() => String(-Math.floor(100 * Math.random() + 1)));
 // (+v) converts the string value to a Number
const meanX = x.reduce((a, v) => a + (+v), 0) / x.length;
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(x)} => Mean: ${meanX}`);

// or as a one liner
console.log(`Mean from one liner: ${
  x.reduce( (a, v) => a + ((1/x.length) * +(v)), 0 ).toFixed(2)}`
);
```